# C# binding is not updating label content

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

Could somebody please tell me about way to solve problem?

I have simple binding where I want to bind label text to "DateTime" property of one of my classes. The problem is, what this binding correctly works only **once** when control is loaded, but it doesn't react later, when I change source property value.

I checked, and I am **sure** what I am changing source property value.
I also tried to use different "UpdateSourceTrigger" values, but there were no difference.

What I did wrong here? Could someone please give some ideas? Thank you in advance.

[image: Control]

```
public CheckListTaskControl(ICheckListTask task)
{
       InitializeComponent();
       _task = task;
       dateFromLabel.SetBinding(Label.ContentProperty,
       new Binding()
       {
           Source = _task.TaskDatePeriod,
           Mode = BindingMode.OneWay,
           Path = new PropertyPath("DateFrom"),
           Converter = new DateTimeFormatConverter(),
           UpdateSourceTrigger = UpdateSourceTrigger.PropertyChanged,
           ConverterParameter = _dateFormat
        });
}}
```

_dateFormat is just string "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm"

Comment: Maybe your property does not notify about value changes, we don't know.

Comment: Could you tell me please, what are you talking about? I am new in C# and wpf, could you tell me more? In guides I watched there were nothing about property notifications.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/33641182/1136211

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/data/?view=netdesktop-6.0

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you do it in a **cleaner way**,

You will create Property in **ViewModel** like this

`public DateTime DateTimeProperty { get; set; }`

Once you have set in your **View** something like this

`<DatePicker SelectedDate="{Binding DateTimeProperty}"/>`

You will be **updated** on any change

Comment: How will this work without `INotifyPropertyChanged` ?

Answer (score 0):

Make a class(inherit it from **INotifyPropertyChanged**) to which your control is bound to implement **INotifyPropertyChanged** interface, then set your `UpdateSourceTrigger` to `PropertyChanged`